# How to return the result of serde_json::from_str when called with a String that will be dropped at the end of the function?

Tags: memory-management, rust, lifetime

I have a newly allocated `String` inside a function, I need to create a derived object that borrows `&str` from that `String`, and return the given object.

I know my code is wrong because the `String` lifetime is that of the function, so the derived object will never be returned because of dangling references.

What would be the idiomatic solution here? I cannot change the signature of `serde_json::from_str`

```
#[inline]
pub fn get_object<'a, T>(json_data: &'a Value, path: &[&str]) -> Option<T>
    where T: serde::Deserialize<'a>
{
    let mut pointer_str = String::new();
    for entry in path.iter() {
        pointer_str = format!("{}/{}", pointer_str, entry);
    }

    let child = json_data.pointer(&pointer_str).unwrap().to_string();

    let result = serde_json::from_str(&child).ok();
    return result;
}
```

And the error:

```
error: `child` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:88:40
   |
88 |     let result = serde_json::from_str(&child).ok();
   |                                        ^^^^^ does not live long enough
89 |     return result;
90 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiomatic solution is either of:

- having `T` implement `DeserializeOwned` instead,
- have two methods: one to create the string, and one to deserialize, and ensure that the deserialized result is stored longer than `T`.

The former is, of course, much easier.