# Deserialize trait bound on generic struct

Tags: rust, lifetime

I want to build a parser for a generic struct by `serde_json`, here is the simplifed logic. And it will generate an error: "`src` does not live long enough".

But why this would cause a not-long-enough lifetime error?

Is there any way to fix it, or it is simply not recommended to write codes like this?

```rust
use serde_json;
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

#[derive(Default)]
struct Parser<'de, P:Deserialize<'de>>{
    phantom1: PhantomData<&'de ()>,
    phantom2: PhantomData<P>,
}

impl<'de, P:Deserialize<'de>> Parser<'de,P>{
    fn parse(&self, src:&'de String){
        serde_json::from_str::<P>(&src).unwrap();
    }
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct OutterParser<'de, P:Deserialize<'de>>{
    parser: Parser<'de, P>
}

impl<'de, P:Deserialize<'de>> OutterParser<'de,P>{
  fn read_and_parse(&self){
    let src = String::from(r#""""#);
    self.parser.parse(&src); 
  }
}

fn main(){
    let parser = OutterParser::<String>::default();
    parser.read_and_parse();
}
```

Here is the [rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9b5bc333398453462fef2c085ff7c031)

---

Edit:
Thanks for the answer from Kevin. I once thought that 'de lifetime would be automatically derived to be a lifetime in the local `parse` function. After `P` struct been built from local `&src`, the `src` can be dropped.

Now I know the lifetime of function arguments would be less than `'de` without evident annotation.

But if the function signature is revised to `fn parse(&self, &'de str)`, the `'de` will be further propagated upwards, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`P: Deserialize<'de>` means that deserializing into a value of type `P` requires input data which must live for at least `'de`.

```rust
    fn parse(&self, src:String){
        serde_json::from_str::<P>(&src).unwrap();
```

Instead, you provided a reference to the local variable `src` which will be dropped at the end of the `parse` function, and therefore definitely lives *shorter* than `'de`.

In order to not have this problem, you must define `parse` such that it accepts a *reference* that is valid for `'de`:

```rust
    fn parse(&self, src: &'de str) {
```

Comment: I have changed the code sample, so that the problem is clearer. Sorry for the misunderstanding I made. Really thanks if you'd like to review it again :)

Comment: @Forsworn If you've received an answer, please do not edit the question into a different one that the answer does not apply to, especially if you are going to accept the answer. It is better to post a new question (you can add links to show how they relate to each other).

Answer (score 1):

Found answer in another question :)
[How to return the result of serde_json::from_str when called with a String that will be dropped at the end of the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178168/how-to-return-the-result-of-serde-jsonfrom-str-when-called-with-a-string-that)

An easier workaround is to use `DeserializeOwned`...

```
use serde_json;
use serde::de::DeserializeOwned;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

#[derive(Default)]
struct Parser<P:DeserializeOwned>{
    phantom2: PhantomData<P>,
}

impl<P:DeserializeOwned> Parser<P>{
    fn parse(&self, src:&String){
        serde_json::from_str::<P>(&src).unwrap();
    }
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct OutterParser<P:DeserializeOwned>{
    parser: Parser<P>
}

impl<P:DeserializeOwned> OutterParser<P>{
  fn read_and_parse(&self){
    let src = String::from(r#""""#);
    self.parser.parse(&src); 
  }
}

fn main(){
    let parser = OutterParser::<String>::default();
    parser.read_and_parse();
}
```